# Wordpress hooks to call a function inside a construct

Tags: functions, hooks, actions

I am trying to call a custom function inside the constructor function. Which action hook to be used?

```
class myClass{

  public function __construct(){

        add_action('$hook', array($this, myFunction);
  }

  public function myFunction(){
      echo "I am called";
   }
}
```

Additionally, I have two questions

1. What would be the intention of private construct instead of public?
2. Which one is better to use; singleton class or the normal call.

Looking forward

Thanks

Comment: When will this function you need make affect on your Wordpress setup will decide the hook. Like if there is a function which you are using for adding menu admin you can make use of `admin_init` there. So, please first explain what will this function do.

Comment: This function is to be executed in single.php for setting up breadcrumb. Thanks

Comment: I think there you will need an `action_hook`. You can use any one of them as per the priority. Please look into this link for choosing our appropriate hook.   https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference